# Firebase Analytics Custom Events Data Is Not Reflecting In Dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

i am trying to log custom events using following code.

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("custom_event") {
    param("event_name", "Push Notification Clicked")
    param("event_message", "Weather is cloudy")
     param("event_device_details", "Samsung Galaxy")
}
```

Currently in events dashboard its displaying only

1. Event count
   2.Total users
   3.Event count per user

But not displaying event_name,event_message,event_device_details information. its been more than 48 hours still its not displaying params details.

But i can see this details RealTime View and Debug View, and not in analytics dashboard.

can some help me why this data is being not reflected ?

Is There any way to fetch this Data using REST API ?